# LESS mixins vs classes

Tags: css, less

I'm looking into LESS because I definitely see some of their benefits. For instance colour declaration.

One thing I don't understand tho, and maybe I'm not getting the flow right is - why use the following LESS snippet

```
.radius {
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;  
}
.btn-red{
  background-color:red;
  .radius;     
}
.btn-green{
  background-color:green;
  .radius;
}
...
```

When we can use the `.radius` class in the html file right away. I'm left with the impression that LESS will add a ton of duplicate code once it gets compiled.

I'm using the following, which makes more sense. Same with font-size, margins, etc... Aren't classes used in such cases?

```
<div class="btn-red radius">Cancel</div>
<div class="btn-green radius">Go</div>
```

Comment: What if you can't modify the HTML? What if you want parameters?

Comment: None of the preprocessors will add duplicate code because all of them are making use of some kind of selector grouping to reduce the compiled code footprint. BTW, try to avoid adding visual references like colors to selector names. I.e. instead of using `btn-red` or `btn-green` call them `btn-primary` or `btn-secondary`.

Comment: @holodoc, that is not true. LESS/SASS will simply copy all radius related rules to both `.btn-red` and `.btn-green`. Preprocessors have no idea how you are going to use the classes so can make no assumptions about possible optimizations/deduplications.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Yes it is true because preprocessors will specifically group selectors that extend other selectors on compile time and therefore eliminate redundancy. It is a feature well documented in both SASS and LESS documentation (http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7).

Comment: These are mixins here, not extensions.

Comment: And in case you need to inherit *just* `.radius` properties (w/o parametrising anything) both Less and Sass provide `extend`: [1](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature), [2](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7). So it's just a matter of the OP treating some tutorial examples as a "goto/must-use" pattern.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Mixins or extensions, it does not matter as far as compiled code is concerned because the end result is always plain CSS. In both cases, preprocessors do optimize the compiled code.

Comment: It does matter. What is OP using and asking about are mixins, and those result in duplicated code. Please check yourself. (And, btw, Novak FTW! ;)

Comment: Btw. and speaking of "a ton of duplicate code". True, but in case of preprocessors these tons are generated automatically (*only* if you want it - see again `extend` above) but if you go your `class="btn-red radius"` way you'll have to write this "a ton of duplicate code" in HTML *manually* :) (well, unless you''re using some HTML preprocessor too of course). So either CSS coding style is always a compromise between balancing code in CSS and HTML (that's why there're zillion of different CSS approaches like OOCSS, ACSS, BEM, SMACSS, WTFELSE etc.)

Comment: Lets say that I would like to have a margin-right:10px to btn-red... Then I would just add class='btn-red radius mR10' and there, i have an offset between the two buttons. Otherwise I have to add a specific class that has to be part of the selector group etc. etc... It doesn't seem flexible to me. I consider css classes as a way to define variables and then use those variables in the HTML.

Comment: @Ando, hardcoding `margin: 10px` (or whatever specific color/size/position) is typically considered as CSS misuse and hints that you're most likely miss the very purpose of it (in fact you don't need CSS for this at all. Vanilla HTML had this since the beginning: `<div style="margin: 10px">`). If you need an "offset" between two buttons it's normally specified via `.btn + .btn` (or similar selector), *not* in HTML (there're always exceptions in real projects of course but those are *exceptions*).

Comment: @Ando Yet, again, read prev. comments - nobody's talking about what coding style you should or should not use (it's just impossible, there can be no universal rule), it's only about understanding when certain approach fits better (that's why I actually voted to close the Q as "too broad" because it's more like of "coding style guidelines" rather then about a specific problem).

Comment: I.e. if you are fine with using HTML like `<div class="btn red-text blue-background arial font-size-16 radius-10px margin-5em padding-2rem absolute-position">`, it's fine, it's totally up to you ;) (just be prepared others will refuse to read/understand/support it).

Answer (score 2):

The snippet above does not benefit from SASS/LESS capabilities that much. Lets have a closer look and check this SCSS snippet.

```
// Abstract placeholder.
%radius {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

// Put your global styling here.
// I'm assuming that you can alter the markup and have button.btn.btn-green
.btn {

  // Color modifier.
  &-red {
    @extend %radius;
    background-color: red;
  }
  &-green {
    @extend %radius;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

The CSS output will be:

```
.btn-red, .btn-green {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.btn-green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

And then you have to pick up [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) and vendor-prefixes issue is solved once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

Because now, you can just specify the class `btn_red` or `btn_green` and all the buttons will automatically have a radius.

Your HTML should contain only the semantics, and styling or classes referring to styling should not be part of it.

That applies to the other classes as well. If for instance, you would rename `btn_red` to `btn_cancel`, you have a meaningful classname that you can apply to any kind of cancel button. And in the CSS you can specify that a cancel button is red and a 'Go' button is green, and both have a radius, without needing to modify the HTML at all.

So, the ultimate goal is to have the HTML describe the structure and the CSS describe how that structure should look. And a CSS preprocessor is only their to make a bulky spaghetti-like CSS file more structured.

Comment: *Copied from my comment in the top discussion* Lets say that I would like to have a margin-right:10px to btn-red... Then I would just add class='btn-red radius mR10' and there, i have an offset between the two buttons. Otherwise I have to add a specific class that has to be part of the selector group etc. etc... It doesn't seem flexible to me. I consider css classes as a way to define variables and then use those variables in the HTML.

Comment: And then you want to make your button purple with square corners and a purple background. And the classes still look like `btn-red radius mR10` unless you refactor all your HTML. So now you not only have styling information in the HTML, but it's incorrect too. Of course it's your decision to do so, I'm just telling you out of experience that it's a bad idea. You could also just inline `style` attributes. Nothing illegal there, but not a good practice.

Comment: I don't see how that is difficult. I just change the classes to .btn-purple, i remove the radius class etc... Where is the other way around I need to find the exact class for that exact button and change it, and what if I don't want to have rounded/square corners of just one of my btn_red buttons? (better example what if I want one of those buttons to have an absolute position, and the rest to be relative, or one to have a color:red; which i have defined in my .cRed selector) ?

Comment: Okay. Then go ahead and do as you like. There is no law against it, just well-meant advice.

Answer (score 1):

There are several benefits.

1. You can use more semantic class names.  Rather than encoding style information directly in your class names, (btn-red, radius) you could use a single class that conveys the usage of the style, rather than its contents.
2. You can avoid repeating yourself.

   `@radius-size: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius:@radius-size;
   -moz-border-radius:@radius-size;
   border-radius:@radius-size;`
3. You can parameterize it so that you'd be able to use different radiuses (radii?) in different contexts.

   `.radius(@radius-size) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Because there are cases that developer has-no-access or don't-want to change the markup. and the only solution is to include all props from a predefined class.

**for example:**

you have bootstrap loaded (then you already have `.has-success` and `.has-error` classes) and if you want to use HTML5's native form validation using input's `:valid` and `:invalid` states, you have to use JavaScript to add/remove success/error classes based on input's states. but with this feature of LESS you can include all props of success/error class inside input's states. the code for this example could be something like this:

```
#myinput {
    &:valid { .has-success; }
    &:invalid { .has-error; }
}
```