# Use of Less Mixins

Tags: css, less

I started learning Less yesterday and I came across Mixins. As an example you could use it like this:

Less/CSS:

```
.class1{
    background-color: blue;
}

.class2{
    .class1;
    color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="class1">Hello World!</div>
<div class="class2">¡Hola Mundo!</div>
```

What is the advantage of this instead of using:

Less/CSS:

```
.class1{
    background-color: blue;
}

.class2{
    color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="class1">Hello World!</div>
<div class="class1 class2">¡Hola Mundo!</div>
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LESS mixins vs classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389198/less-mixins-vs-classes)

Comment: It allows you to make your styles more modular.